# Reset increment value in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

how do I reset the increment count in flask-sqlalchemy after deleting a row so that the next insert will get the id of deleted row?
ie :

```
table users:
user_id | name |
________________
3       | mbuvi
4       | meshack
5       | You
```

when I delete user with id=5;
the next insertion into users is having id = 6 but I want it to have id=5;

```
user_id | name |
________________
3       | mbuvi
4       | meshack
6       | me
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: To set the increment count, here's the sql command: ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = number; Don't know if their a sqlalchemy 
method that do the same thing.

Comment: Like how do you do it using flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: Try db.engine.execute("ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 5")

Answer (score 0):

Your database will keep track your auto increment id! so you can't do something like this.BTW it's no about the `flask-sqlalchemy` question! If you really want to do this, you have to calculater the left id which you can used and fill it with that number! for example:

```
+----+--------+
| id | number |
+----+--------+
|  1 |    819 |
|  2 |    829 |
|  4 |    829 |
|  5 |    829 |
+----+--------+
```

And you have to find the id (3) and then insert with id. so this cause a query all the table util you got that position! don't no why you need to do this, but still have solution!

step01, you gotta use a cache to do this! here I recommand use `redis`

step02, If you want to delete any row, just simply cache your `id` into the `redis list`, the `Order-Set` is best optionl for you! before delete any row, save it to the cache!

step03, before insert any new row, check see if there any id aviable in your `redis`! if true, pop it out and insert it with the `id` which you pop out!

step04, the code should like below:

```
def insert_one(data):
   r = redis.Redis()
   _id = r.pop('ID_DB')
   if _id:
      cursor.execute("insert into xxx(id, data)values(%s, %s)", data)
   else:
      # use default increment id
      cursor.execute("insert into xxx(data)values(%s)", data)

def delete(data, id):
      # query the target which you will delete
      # if you delete by condtion `id` that's best
      r = redis.Redis()
      r.push('ID_DB',id)
      # DO the rest of you want ...
      # delete ....
```